# django model foreign key to one in a list of models

Tags: python, django

I have a Profile class which I like to use for my CustomUser and Shipper classes. Is there a way to tell django that `models.ForeignKey(to=[CustomUser, Shipper])` in Profile model so that my profile would have a foreign key to EITHER CustomUser OR Shipper models?
I tried putting `models.ForeignKey(to=[Profile])` in both CustomUser and Shipper classes but the problem is that when I try to run `py manage.py createsuperuser` I face and error saying I violate NOT NULL rule and I must set a profile for my superuser.
I also tried to put Shipper and CustomUser into an ABSTRACT parent class and set this relation of `models.ForeignKey(to=[Profile])` in parent but again the problem is that django does not allow to have foregin key to abstract classes
I do can put a foreign key relationship in both Shipper and CustomUser models but I think this is not the best practise.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, you cannot directly create a `ForeignKey` to multiple models. However, you can achieve a similar effect by using `generic relations`. In your case, you can use Django's `GenericForeignKey` to create a relationship between the Profile model and both `CustomUser` and `Shipper` models.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Profile(models.Model):
    # Your other fields in the Profile model

    # GenericForeignKey fields
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    # Your fields in the CustomUser model
    profiles = GenericRelation(Profile)

class Shipper(models.Model):
    # Your fields in the Shipper model
    profiles = GenericRelation(Profile)
```

now you can query for each type like this

```
# Get all profiles associated with CustomUser
custom_user_profiles = Profile.objects.filter(content_type__model='customuser')

# Get all profiles associated with Shipper
shipper_profiles = Profile.objects.filter(content_type__model='shipper')
```